# Benchmarking result of EBS and SSD doesn't have much difference

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, solid-state-drive

I have attached an `SSD` and an `EBS` volume to my `EC2` instance. I have formatted them both with `ext4` filesystem. I wanted to be sure that `SSD` does perform better than the `EBS` volume. I ran a benchmarking script using `fio`. Here are the result from the tests.

For EBS,

```
# fio --directory=/mnt/ssd/bm --name fio_test_file --direct=1 --rw=randwrite --bs=16k --size=1G --numjobs=5 --time_based --runtime=180 --group_reporting     --norandommap
fio_test_file: (g=0): rw=randwrite, bs=16K-16K/16K-16K/16K-16K, ioengine=sync, iodepth=1
...
fio-2.1.10
Starting 5 processes
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
Jobs: 5 (f=5): [wwwww] [100.0% done] [0KB/48848KB/0KB /s] [0/3053/0 iops] [eta 00m:00s]
fio_test_file: (groupid=0, jobs=5): err= 0: pid=11053: Thu May  4 11:43:34 2017
  write: io=8643.8MB, bw=49173KB/s, iops=3073, runt=180002msec
    clat (usec): min=509, max=145942, avg=1624.43, stdev=1506.86
     lat (usec): min=510, max=145942, avg=1624.97, stdev=1506.86
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  612],  5.00th=[  668], 10.00th=[  716], 20.00th=[  852],
     | 30.00th=[ 1384], 40.00th=[ 1544], 50.00th=[ 1592], 60.00th=[ 1624],
     | 70.00th=[ 1656], 80.00th=[ 1704], 90.00th=[ 1768], 95.00th=[ 2040],
     | 99.00th=[ 9280], 99.50th=[ 9920], 99.90th=[10944], 99.95th=[12480],
     | 99.99th=[18560]
    bw (KB  /s): min= 7094, max=18976, per=20.02%, avg=9843.42, stdev=732.08
    lat (usec) : 750=13.25%, 1000=10.92%
    lat (msec) : 2=70.59%, 4=2.20%, 10=2.61%, 20=0.42%, 50=0.01%
    lat (msec) : 100=0.01%, 250=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=0.24%, sys=1.48%, ctx=553431, majf=0, minf=147
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=0/w=553200/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: io=8643.8MB, aggrb=49172KB/s, minb=49172KB/s, maxb=49172KB/s, mint=180002msec, maxt=180002msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  xvdg: ios=0/553547, merge=0/17739, ticks=0/902997, in_queue=903007, util=100.00%
```

For SSD,

```
# fio --directory=/mnt/ebs/bm --name fio_test_file --direct=1 --rw=randwrite --bs=16k --size=1G --numjobs=5 --time_based --runtime=180 --group_reporting     --norandommap
fio_test_file: (g=0): rw=randwrite, bs=16K-16K/16K-16K/16K-16K, ioengine=sync, iodepth=1
...
fio-2.1.10
Starting 5 processes
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_test_file: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
Jobs: 5 (f=5): [wwwww] [100.0% done] [0KB/28992KB/0KB /s] [0/1812/0 iops] [eta 00m:00s]
fio_test_file: (groupid=0, jobs=5): err= 0: pid=11264: Thu May  4 11:47:03 2017
  write: io=5362.9MB, bw=30508KB/s, iops=1906, runt=180002msec
    clat (usec): min=718, max=252941, avg=2619.54, stdev=4676.50
     lat (usec): min=718, max=252942, avg=2620.13, stdev=4676.50
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[ 1064],  5.00th=[ 1144], 10.00th=[ 1208], 20.00th=[ 1336],
     | 30.00th=[ 1560], 40.00th=[ 1768], 50.00th=[ 1960], 60.00th=[ 2224],
     | 70.00th=[ 2640], 80.00th=[ 3248], 90.00th=[ 4448], 95.00th=[ 5792],
     | 99.00th=[ 9664], 99.50th=[12352], 99.90th=[26496], 99.95th=[51968],
     | 99.99th=[211968]
    bw (KB  /s): min= 2629, max= 8064, per=20.05%, avg=6115.34, stdev=955.82
    lat (usec) : 750=0.01%, 1000=0.14%
    lat (msec) : 2=51.83%, 4=35.34%, 10=11.77%, 20=0.75%, 50=0.11%
    lat (msec) : 100=0.01%, 250=0.04%, 500=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=0.17%, sys=1.05%, ctx=343487, majf=0, minf=142
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=0/w=343220/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: io=5362.9MB, aggrb=30508KB/s, minb=30508KB/s, maxb=30508KB/s, mint=180002msec, maxt=180002msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  xvdf: ios=0/344272, merge=0/26549, ticks=0/947340, in_queue=947338, util=100.00%
```

I cant see much improvement in the performance (At least as much as I had expected). I want to know if I have done something wrong here or this is how it is. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are you sure you are comparing two different things? According to the documentation:  Amazon EBS provides the following volume types: General Purpose SSD (gp2), Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1), Throughput Optimized HDD (st1), Cold HDD (sc1), and Magnetic (standard).

Comment: I have Magnetic standard and GP2 attached .. None of them are IO optimized.

Comment: Alright, so maybe you should ask about the difference between magnetic and gp2 then.

Comment: I know they are different things. One is a Magnetic Disk and another one is an SSD